# convert MM/DD/YYYY to DD/MM/YYYY

Tags: c#, .net

I have date in format "MM/DD/YYYY" e.g. "09/25/2011", how i can convert this in format "DD/MM/YYYY".

my code is:

```
private DateTime GetDate()
{
  string d = Convert.ToDateTime("09/25/2011").ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"); //returns 25/09/2011
  DateTime date = DateTime.Parse(d, new CultureInfo("en-GB")); 
  return date;// returns 09/25/2011
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Format is not matter until you not displaying it somewhere, perhaps you need to get string representation in this format?

Comment: what do you mean in second line by saying `"returns"`?

Comment: i want this in datetime format.

Comment: `DateTime` doesn't have a "format". It has some internal representation. Strings that _represent_ a date/time have a format.

Comment: First of all tell me that who has given it negative vote? first answer this question then given negative vote.

Comment: @Sami - Voting is anonymous. Please grow up.

Comment: @Oded: yes i know this is anonymous but there should be restriction for valid and invalid questions.

Comment: What are you talking about? Someone thought the question was bad so voted it down (seeing as you have a misunderstanding about formats and DateTime, not too surprising). You are then responding with threats.

Comment: @Sami - If you don't want negative votes, ask a better question, this questions shows you have no idea how DateTime works which makes it tough to work with.  If you are getting an error, post the code you are using and the error, otherwise we cannot help you.  Of course at this point the answer is unlikely to be salvaged.

Answer (score 12):

Have you tried formatting the `date` object as `dd/MM/yyyy`?

```
string d = Convert.ToDateTime("09/25/2011").ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"); //returns 25/09/2011
DateTime date = DateTime.Parse("09/25/2011", new CultureInfo("en-GB")); // returns 09/25/2011
string d2 = date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"); //should return 25/09/2011
```

Comment: it should return DateTime not string.

Comment: only this line string d = Convert.ToDateTime("09/25/2011").ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"); also gives the result other two lines are not necessary i want result in datetime not in string.

Comment: @Sami - What do you mean it should return a DateTime, you do understand that you could simple parse the string in this example as a DateTime, and get exactly what you want?

Comment: @Ramhound: yes i know but when i parse it into datetime then it throws me error that string is not in correct format.

Comment: @Sami: You can't assign a DateTime Object to a string. You have to convert it, that's what the ToString()-Method ist doing. Why do you even have a string there if you don't want it as a string?

Comment: I suggest this modification  `DateTime date = DateTime.Parse("09/25/2011", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToShortDate();`

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest your function just does the following...

```
private DateTime GetDate()
{
   return DateTime.ParseExact("09/25/2011", "MM/dd/yyyy", null);
}
```

Then when you use the function...

```
string formattedDate = GetDate().ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Comment: this works fine and i have done this but when i convert this in datetime then it throws error. How to convert this in datetime format?

Comment: @Sami: I dont know what you mean. What is your input and what type/format do you want as output?

Comment: my input is date in string format e.g "09/25/2011" and i want to convert it into DateTime in UK format.

Comment: @Sami: So you just need to use my first bit of code - the function called GetDate. Once you have a DateTime object, there is no format for that. The only time you need to worry about the format is when you need to display it - at which point you can use the second part of my code to get a UK formatted string

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
DateTime mmddyyy = Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.ParseExact("11222019", "MMddyyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
string dateddMMyyyy = mmddyyy.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
```

Answer (score -2):

```
string input = Console.ReadLine();

 string[] dtarray = input.Split('/');

DateTime datechanged = new DateTime(Convert.ToInt32(dtarray[2]),Convert.ToInt32(dtarray[1]),Convert.ToInt32(dtarray[0]));
```